# Bootstrap selectpicker, on select event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have a bootstrap selectpicker which is working good (event is fired when selected).
I have a code, which is creating 2nd selectpicker when 1st (which is working) is changed.
The problem is, that this 2nd selectpicker is not firing an event when it is selected (like if i do "alert" on "change" with jQuery).
Tried a few fixes, readed about the native events, but they did not worked...

```
var selector = $(this).closest('.product-item-options');
flavourTemplate = '<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4"><div class="tree-design"><span></span><span class="middle-sep"></span><span></span></div></div><div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8"><select id="product-' + product + '-flavour-' + j + '" name="flavour[' + j + ']" class="selectpicker spec-selectpicker product-flavours other-flavours">';
                // flavourSelect are the options
                flavourTemplate += flavourSelect;
                flavourTemplate += '</select></div></div>';
                selector.append(flavourTemplate);
                $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('render');
                $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

And here is the simple JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.selectpicker').on('changed.bs.select', function (e) {
       alert('changed');
    });
});
```

Comment: can you provide a working jsfiddle?

Comment: It will be hard, because this is part of bigger code, thats the part where I'm adding the selectpicker, It is being added correctly, but simply not providing on-change event...

Comment: do you have _"document ready"_ declared?

Comment: @threeFatCat yes, will update the question and add the code in a sec, and as i said, it is working for the selectpicker which is not added from the code, the one which is initial is ok

Comment: @LubomirLubenov, ah no. I'm asking for the part where you coded `var selector` that should be also inside _document ready_. Though it will run in some occasion without the _document ready_ but most likely it will output undesirable behavior without it.

Comment: @threeFatCat yes it is in another function, it runs well because selectpicker is added, but dont trigger the onchange event

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem for myself this way:

```
$('#mySelect').parent().find("input").bind('keyup', (event) => {
  // your code
})
```

(Of course, you can use any another selector to find your select first)